# Can't debug next 13.4.x /app router application

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13

I'm running a Next.js app using the `/app` router, and cannot attach a debugger to the server-side process.

In terms of reproducing, just creating a next app using `npx create-next-app` and chooising to use the app router option is sufficient to reproduce the behavior.

I have tried attaching a debugger to the node process, or running the process directly from vscode using the [suggested](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/debugging#debugging-with-vs-code) VSCode debug parameters. However, these parameters are for the `/pages` router, and it seems like there is no corresponding version for the app router.

Any help or further clarification I could give is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use below codes in lunch.json file. It worked for me. I am using app router.

// package.json

```
{
  "name": "starter",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.48.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.19",
    "next": "13.4.19",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  }
}
```

// lunch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Next.js: debug server-side",
            "type": "node-terminal",
            "request": "launch",
            "command": "npm run dev"
        },
        {
            "name": "Next.js: debug client-side",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000"
        },
        {
            "name": "Next.js: debug full stack",
            "type": "node-terminal",
            "request": "launch",
            "command": "npm run dev",
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "started server on .+, url: (https?://.+)",
                "uriFormat": "%s",
                "action": "debugWithChrome"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Embarassingly, using this configuration and just setting the breakpoint worked. It looks like, even though VSCode *thinks* the breakpoint is unbound, it is, in fact, bound, and will work.

```
{
      "name": "Next.js: debug full stack",
      "type": "node-terminal",
      "request": "launch",
      "command": "npm run dev",
      "serverReadyAction": {
        "pattern": "- Local:.+(https?://.+)",
        "uriFormat": "%s",
        "action": "debugWithChrome"
      }
    }
```

Source: [Next.js `/pages` router docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/debugging#debugging-with-vs-code)